Google Apps Script. Using google.script.host.close() is no longer closing my modal dialog
My Google Workspace add-on shows modals with documentApp.getUi().showModalDialog
When I close the modal with (client side)  google.script.host.close  ...
the modal does not close.
Console log shows "Uncaught TypeError: this.H.dispatchEvent is not a
function".
at B.rzb (1148544181-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:3190:707)
at rt.o (3093671068-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:312:329)

This used to work.... and has worked for months.  Happening with every modal in my add-on.
// Code.gs
function onHomepage(e) {

    var builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();

    var section = CardService.newCardSection();

    var textButton = CardService.newTextButton();
    textButton.setText('Do a thing');

    var action = CardService.newAction();
    action.setFunctionName("doAThing");

    textButton.setOnClickAction(action);

    textButton.setDisabled(false);

    var widget = section.addWidget(textButton);

    builder.addSection(section);

    return builder.build();
}


function doAThing() {
    var th = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("doAThing");

    th.evaluate();
    th.setHeight(230);
    th.setWidth(230);

    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    ui.showModalDialog(th, "Do a Cool Thing");
}

// doAThing.html
< !DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <p>A Cool Thing</p>
        </div>


        <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeModal()" />

        <script>
            function closeModal() {
                google.script.host.close();
                }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>


Please provide [mcve]

Are you missing these ()

Edited to include minimal reproducible example.   Yes, I'm including the parenthesis on the function call.

The problem seems to have gone away by itself.  I'll add a comment here if I'm able to determine what caused this and what resolved it.
